# How to manage implicit groups in record rules?

Tags: python, odoo

I am currently learning how to use Odoo. I am doing the following [tutorial](https://www.odoo.com/documentation/15.0/fr/developer/howtos/rdtraining/01_architecture.html) and i am at the *advanced topic ACL And Records rules* at the Record Rules part.

I produced the following .xml file by doing the tutorial from the beginning

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<odoo>

    <record id="estate_group_user" model="res.groups">
        <field name="name">Agent</field>
        <field name="category_id" ref="base.module_category_real_estate_brokerage"/>
    </record>

    <record id="estate_group_manager" model="res.groups">
        <field name="name">Manager</field>
        <field name="category_id" ref="base.module_category_real_estate_brokerage"/>
        <field name="implied_ids" eval="[(4, ref('estate_group_user'))]"/>
    </record>

    <record id="estate_user_rule" model="ir.rule">
        <field name="name">Agent rule</field>
        <field name="model_id" ref="model_estate_property"/>
        <field name="perm_create" eval="False"/>
        <field name="perm_unlink" eval="False"/>
        <field name="groups" eval="[Command.link(ref('estate.estate_group_user'))]"/>
        <field name="domain_force">[
            '|',
            ('salesman_id','=', user.id),
            ('salesman_id', '=', None)]</field>
    </record>

</odoo>
```

The idea is to create user groups in an application that manages real estate properties, an "Agent" group and a "Manager" group.

The instruction is to create a rule that allows agents to see or modify only properties for which they are the sellers or that do not have sellers.

What I don't understand is that previously in the tutorial it says :  `The estate_group_manager group needs to imply estate_group_user`

which led me to add the following line in the group manager:  `<field name="implied_ids" eval="[(4, ref('estate_group_user'))]"/>`

The consequence of this is that a user who is in the Manager group is also in the Agent group. The rule will therefore also apply to managers.I guess this problem is expected, as it is written in the tutorial:

> Verify that your real estate manager(s) can still see all properties. If not, why not? Remember:
> The estate_group_manager group needs to imply estate_group_user.

This is exactly my problem.

I don't understand what is the solution expected by the tutorial. It works by deleting `<field name="implieds_ids"...` but I have the impression that this is not the right thing to do.

Thank you in advance for your answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As odoo's tutorial says, a good practice while creating group roles hierarchy is to let powerful roles inherit minor roles.

This means your manager group will also inherit agent visibility rules.
To avoid this, you need to override that visibility role only for manager group.

```
<record id="estate_user_rule" model="ir.rule">
        <field name="name">Agent rule</field>
        <field name="model_id" ref="model_estate_property"/>
        <field name="perm_create" eval="False"/>
        <field name="perm_unlink" eval="False"/>
        <field name="groups" eval="[Command.link(ref('estate.estate_group_user'))]"/>
        <field name="domain_force">[
            '|',
            ('salesman_id','=', user.id),
            ('salesman_id', '=', None)]</field>
</record>

<record id="estate_manager_rule" model="ir.rule">
        <field name="name">Manager rule</field>
        <field name="model_id" ref="model_estate_property"/>
        <field name="perm_create" eval="True"/>
        <field name="perm_unlink" eval="True"/>
        <field name="groups" eval="[Command.link(ref('estate.estate_group_manager'))]"/>
        <field name="domain_force">[]</field>
</record>
```

Comment: It works, thank you.  The lines `perm_create` , `perm_unlink` are not necessary because it is implicitly `True` if I understood correctly, but it will help to understand when I will come back in this part. What confuses me is that throughout the tutorial I had taken the habit on my IDE to search in the Odoo source code, examples as they advise, but I did not see any use case  `<field name="domain_force">[]</field>` . Thanks for your help.

Comment: There should be a lot of examples like in sales, project or hr apps.

Comment: I must be searching wrong then, CTRL + SHIFT + F in IntelliJ Ultimate, I search "In Project" , `"domain_force">[]</field>` , the only example it finds is the one I just filled.

Comment: Another interesting and probably important hint: these "group rules" (ir.rule with group and therefor not global) are logically combined OR, that's why the manager rule works that easy.

Comment: That's because usually in Odoo such "all records" domains are `[(1, '=', 1)]`.

Comment: And there, magic! There are a ton of examples. Thank you.